# Pyautogui inactivity detection

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a pyautogui code that repeats a order to click on a webpage but sometimes that webpage freezes and does not load, how could i detect that.

> the webpage in not on selenium and chrome has been opened by pyautogui too

**Update 1:**
I have just realised that the website will realise that i have been on the website for a long time so it will not load certain elements. This usually happens evry 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem by simply reloading the page every 20 minutes which solved the problem.